# How to work with copy of an array and reset it later

Tags: coffeescript

I have an array `list` with all the predefined data I want to work on.

Then I want to make a copy of that array on which I do the work, i.e. shuffling and then popping one element. Now after the list is empty, I want to reset it, i.e. fill it again with the contents of `list`.

What I have now is this:

```
list = [{...}, {...}, {...}]
list2 = list

shuffle = (a) ->
  i = a.length
  while --i > 0
    j = ~~(Math.random() * (i + 1))
    t = a[j]
    a[j] = a[i]
    a[i] = t
  a

get_list_item = ->
  shuffle(list2)
  list2.pop()

reset_list = ->
  list2 = list
```

But after I've popped all the items from `list2`, `reset_list()` doesn't reset the list. It's still empty

Comment: CoffeeScript is a whitespace language, I see a bit of problems about indentation, is that just a  copy paste issue?

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni that's just a copy paste issue, fixing it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list2 = list` doesn't make a copy of `list`, it just creates another pointer to the same array. So when you are using `pop()` the original (and only) array loses elements.

Replace these instructions with `list2 = list.slice 0` and it should work like you want it to.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. I thought that `list2` would simply have the same contents as `list`.